# PL/SQL Storage error in Select Query

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, oracle11g

I have following cursor definition

```
cMultiplier     NUMBER := 100000000000000000 ;
CURSOR CR_TABLE1 IS 
SELECT to_char((COL_ID * cMultiplier) + SEQ,'0999999999999999999') "NEW_COL" 
FROM TABLE1;
```

Then this cursor is being fetched as

```
FETCH CR_TABLE1 
BULK COLLECT INTO AR_TABLE1 LIMIT I_BULK_LIMIT;
EXIT WHEN AR_TABLE1.COUNT = 0;
```

Where `AR_TABLE1` is of type

```
TYPE T_TABLE1 IS TABLE OF CR_TABLE1%ROWTYPE;
AR_TABLE1 T_TABLE1;
```

The test values for `COL_ID` is `1` for all cases and the test values for `SEQ` is `1234567654322` (13 digit number). This value is being inserted as of length 19 in another table of type `VARCHAR`.

The problem is No sooner the cursor comes to `FETCH`, it throws exception stating `ORA-06500: PL/SQL: storage error`

I know it has to do something with select statement, but i am converting it into a string (varchar). Why i am running into this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What value are you assigning to `I_BULK_LIMIT`?

The PLS-06500 error often means the application has run out of memory.  So you need to look at the variables you assign in your program.  But the memory used by the array is the most likely culprit.  If the limit is currently set to more than a few thousand you should consider setting a lower limit.

Comment: I was assuming if the `I_BULK_LIMIT` is null it will be set to `1000`. But it wasn't. So the cursor was fetching values based on `NULL` limit. I figured this thing out by myself yesterday but thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your mask, oracle adds a leading space for positive numbers or a "-" for negative numbers, this is causing the resulting string to be of 20 characters. Add FM to the format (like this: `FM0999999999999999999`). That way Oracle will suppress the leading space.

Comment: It didn't help. I am still running into this error `-6500`. The error occurs when i fetch the data, rather at the time of insert.

Comment: I ran the script for a thousand records and it works ok, what about a memory issue?, can you run it only for a few records? what is I_BULK_LIMIT value?